# jquery autocomplete feature ampersand(&)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, autosuggest

My problem is with jquery autocomplete when i search the string `"AT"` it gives me all the suggestions starting with `"AT"` but in the database the data is present something like `AT&T`
the suggestion given by the autocomplete feature is only AT and when i select the `"AT"` from the suggestions the entered value is `"AT&T"`. This problem is occuring in IE8 and i want the full AT&T data.Please help me

```
$(function(){

         $("input#asp_id").autocomplete("/asp/aspSuggestions.jsp?command=asp-suggestion",{ 
             mustMatch: true,
             matchContains: true,
             matchCase: true
            });  
    });
```

Comment: In your php file that returns the suggestions make sure to use htmlspecialchars on the title of the suggestion (so that & gets transformed the html &amp;)

Comment: i didn't understand your answer ,and i m using jsp not php

Comment: sorry, didn't see you were using asp, but my answer is still valid. in this file : /asp/aspSuggestions.jsp?command=asp-suggestion , make sure each json string returned has the html entities encode (so AT&T => AT&amp;T)

Comment: thanx it works i just replace & with the &amp;

Comment: @Tanatos one problem is there when i select the AT&T then the value is displaying as AT&amp;T

Comment: have a look at this : http://www.naveen.com.au/javascript/jquery/encode-or-decode-html-entities-with-jquery/289

Comment: @Tanatos how i am going to get all the responses ?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response